# I do not understand this expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have to simplify this expression:

$14/9k + 11/9 -2k + 2/9 +2/9k - 6$

What I did at first was combine the like terms and got:

1.) $14/9k - 18/9k + 2/9k = - 6/9k$

2.) $11/9 + 2/9 - 6 = 13/9 - 6/1 = -41/9$

3.) My answer was $-6/9k - -41/9$

I got the answer wrong and I don't know which step I messed up on. What are the steps because I thought I had to combine the like terms and then simplify them?

Answer (score 4):

You made a careless mistake:

$$\frac{14k-18k+2k}{9}=\frac{-4k+2k}{9}=\frac{-\color{red}2k}{9}$$

Also, I notice you used double negative at the very end.

Comment: But what does $14/9k$ mean? Is it $14/(9k)$, or $(14/9)k$? The way it is written, I assumed the former, whereas you assumed the latter. Not that it makes any difference to the eventual answer of $-2/9k$ $-$ the ambiguity cancels itself out :-)

Comment: @Siong Thye Goh  Thank you! I just realized that. I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to the task. Ask questions, I will try to answer them.

$14/9k + 11/9 - 2k + 2/9 + 2/9k - 6 = (14/9k - 2k + 2/9k) + 11/9 + 2/9 - 6 = (16/9k - 2k) + 13/9 - 6 = (16/9k - 18/9k) - 41/9 = -2/9k - 41/9 = -1/9(2k + 41)$